# MySQL : compare string with the result of a query

Tags: mysql

Is it possible to compare the result of a query to a string in MySQL? Something like :

```
select case when 'Captain' = (select role from roleassociation ra
inner join users urs
on ra.userentityid = urs.invuserid
where invuserid = 007)
        then 'true' else 'false' end as result;
```

The above query is incorrect, but is it possible to implement? Thanks in advance.

Comment: paste the tables and output you want to achieve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would probably just put the `CASE` expression in the subquery:

```
SELECT
    CASE WHEN role = 'Captain' THEN 'true' ELSE 'result' END AS result
FROM roleassociation ra
INNER JOIN users urs
    ON ra.userentityid = urs.invuserid
WHERE
    invuserid = 007;
```

Assuming you expect the result to be only a single record, you will still have just a single result with this approach.